# C# - SQL procedure that takes an argument and gives a value back

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing an app for a class, and I've got working stored procedures for insert, delete, alter, and view.

But this one takes an argument and then gives another value back. How do I implement this in my code?

This is the SQL:

```
USE [ADK_DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [IO].[usp_ukupno_donacija_prema_tipu_krg]    Script Date: 3/31/2020 6:52:14 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [IO].[usp_ukupno_donacija_prema_tipu_krg]
@krg_id smallint
as
begin
declare @sum int
select @sum = [IO].[fn_broj_donacija_tip_krg](@krg_id)
print @sum
end;
```

And this is what I got for code:

```
    public void DohvatiDonacijePoKG(string krgId)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[IO].[usp_ukupno_donacija_prema_tipu_krg]", cnn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@krg_id", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = krgId;

        // Return the output from the database

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Success.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Execption: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use an output parameter:

```
ALTER procedure [IO].[usp_ukupno_donacija_prema_tipu_krg]
@krg_id smallint, @sum INT OUT
as
begin
   set @sum = [IO].[fn_broj_donacija_tip_krg](@krg_id);
end;
```

A stored procedure could return values in a few ways:

- SELECT resultset
- output parameter
- RETURN ...; (only single INT value)
- PRINT message (you need to intercept it - [SqlConnection.InfoMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage?view=netframework-4.8))

Comment: Okay, any idea how i get that output to my app?

Comment: @SebastianMarjanović     `command.Parameters.Add("@sum", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: I'd go as far as to say "**The** way is to use output parameter", not just one way. Yes theoretically you can use the other methods you have suggested to return a scalar value, but you shouldn't: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT or RETURN instead of OUTPUT](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output). *(It is an old article, but everything it says is still true today)*

Comment: RETURN should be used for returning the execution status ideally. Whether it was successful or failure or some other status. If we want to return result set, ideally we have to use either OUTPUT parameter(as you have suggested) or SELECT resutlset

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can pass the output parameter like the below one. You can refer to *[How To Use Output Parameter In Stored Procedure In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/example-on-how-to-use-output-parameter-in-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp)*.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Guid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters["@Guid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters["@ClientName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: How does `cmd` relate to the question? Is it the same as `command`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This answer only shows how to use the output parameter in C# only. As in another answer, it has only shown how to declare an output parameter in SQL Server.